# Squashed 3-sphere?

Tags: gravity, quantum-gravity, metric-tensor, topology

What is a squashed 3-sphere? In context of quantum gravity. I stumbled upon a term 'squashed 7 sphere' but that's concerning supersymmetry.

Is it just normal 3-sphere metric, that is just 'squashed' at the poles or is it something entirely different?

Google gave no meaningful answer, other the hundreds of articles just mentioning that term without references (like it's something given, that everybody knows).

Comment: The following articles seem to define it.  It looks as though it's simply the three-sphere with an additional warping parameter that is only applied to a certain part of the metric: http://arxiv.org/abs/1102.4716, http://arxiv.org/abs/1109.4734

Comment: Oh, so that's where all the similarity with warped AdS${}_3$ comes from. Just a warped sphere in a sense...

Comment: Yep that's my impression.  I didn't read too carefully, but if you just look at eq. (2) of the second paper, and note that the sphere corresponds to $v=1$ (see the discussion right after eq. (6)), then I think it's pretty clear something like that is going on.  I would be curious, however, to know if this beast can be pictured in some illuminating way.

Comment: Yeah, that was what I was thinking. It's not really intuitive. I would expect something that was more standard 3 sphere metric looking... But thanks nonetheless :)